# Mysql Query Browser does not run

Tags: mysql-workbench

Suddenly, a blue screen appeared on the computer, and after that, the error appeared and the Mysql Query Browser did not run with the error. I've already reinstalled it, but it remains the same. What should I do?

[Exception EmyxError in module MySQLQueryBrowser.exe at 0010F992 / Error while loaing store connections.Error Nunber 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLCdS.png)

Comment: Remove it an use its successor, called mysql workbench?

Comment: I have to use this for unavoidable reasons.

Comment: Then I suggest to ask your question at mysql's support forum as this is not a programming or software development related question.